# Angular, usar mesmo scope entre controles

Tags: angularjs, controles

Uma dúvida para expert em angular, para eu usar um scope em diversos controllers de um módulo, só consigo com `service(factory)` e ou `rootScope`? Estou numa situação meio bizarra. Temos um projeto que o cliente tem um problema no banco de dados, demora em média de 40segundos para o banco apresentar um dado novo inputado na chamada get. Eles querem que eu coloque o dado seco no scope dos outros controllers, imaginem, vai dar vários problemas. Além do resources e da entidade que faz os get/post, vou ter que ficar adicionando no 'seco' os scopes entre os `controllers, cruds, modulos`. Vai ficar uma zona, cheio de ctrl c e ctrl v, alguém tem alguma dica para eu sair dessa enrascada, vai ficar horrível :(.

Comment: Se o que precisa é compartilhar dados entre escopos, o ideal é centralizar esses dados em um service e os escopos apenas refletirem estes dados. Compartilhar escopos é um anti-pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilize um `service` para conter os valores a serem compartilhados.

Quando for necessário que um dos *controllers* altere um valor, use um método do *service* que armazene localmente o valor e utilize `$scope.$broadcast` para emitir um aviso a todos os *controllers* que o valor foi alterado.

Dentro de cada *controller*, utilize `$rootScope.$on` para monitorar as alterações e atualizar o `$scope` local.