# Manipular um array dinamicamente com vários controllers do Angular.js

Tags: json, angularjs

Bem, tenho uma funcionalidade em meu sistema que tem uma grande
interação com o usuário final, logo optei em empregar o *Angular.js*.

Meu objetivo é popular um *array* dinamicamente e quando
o usuário der submit eu enviar tais dados via *$http.post()* para uma *action*
em meu servidor que irá "parsear" tal *array* para meu objeto (reponsabilidade atrelada ao *Jackson*).

Mas o problema é que não sei como realizar isso de uma maneira correta,
pois tenho 2 modais em minha tela no qual toda vez em que eu apertar "Adicionar"
uma lista será populada dinamicamente na tela e tais dados serão incluidos nessa arvore.

Abaixo tenho a arvore do meu objeto na qual eu quero adicionar os dados via angular.

```
customerData = {
                    "idCustomer":null,
                    "tenantId":null,
                    "birthDate":$scope.birthDate,
                    "email":$scope.email,
                    "firstName":$scope.firstName,
                    "gender":$scope.gender,
                    "lastName":$scope.lastName,
                    "document":{
                       "id":null,
                       "tenantId":null,
                       "rg":$scope.customerRg,
                       "cpf":$scope.customerCpf
                    },
                    "customerPhone":{
                       "id":null,
                       "tenantId":null,
                       "celPhone":$scope.customerCelPhone,
                       "homePhone":$scope.customerHomePhone,
                       "workPhone":$scope.customerWorkPhone
                    },
                    "passenger":null,
                    "customerAddress":{
                       "id":null,
                       "tenantId":null,
                       "cep":$scope.customerAddressCep,
                       "complement":$scope.customerAddressComplement,
                       "number":$scope.customerAddressNumber,
                       "quarter":$scope.customerAddressQuarter,
                       "street":$scope.customerAddressStreet,
                       "city":$scope.customerAddressCity,
                       "state":$scope.customerAddressState,
                       "country":null
                    },
                    "observations":$scope.observations,
                    "site":false,
                    "customerService":{
                       "id":null,
                       "tenantId":null,
                       "date": new Date.now(),
                       "averageBudget":null,
                       "situation":true,
                       "serviceItem":[{
                       }],
                       "history":[{
                          "id":null,
                          "tenantId":null,
                          "register": "Primeiro Atendimento",
                       }],
                       "serviceObservations": "Xpto"
                    }
                 };
```

De exemplo eu tenho um controller no qual irá adicionar no *serviceItem* dados em forma de lista:

```
app.controller('RequestedDestinationModalController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.addReqDestiantion = function(){
        this.customerData.customerService.serviceItem.push({
            "id":null,
            "destination":$scope.destinationModalCtrl.destination,
            "customerService":null,
            "tenantId":null,
            "valueNegotiated":$scope.destinationModalCtrl.valueNegotiated,
            "saleType":$scope.destinationModalCtrl.saleType,
            "departureDate":$scope.destinationModalCtrl.departureDate,
            "arrivalDate":$scope.destinationModalCtrl.arrivalDate,
            "seeIn":$scope.destinationModalCtrl.seeIn,
            "requestedDestination":$scope.destinationModalCtrl.requestedDestination,
            "negociationObservations":$scope.destinationModalCtrl.negociationObservations
         });
    };
}]);
```

Mas no caso eu precisaria deixar meu *array* que contem as chaves dos objetos armazenadas em algum lugar para respectivamente manipula-lo. Ai que mora a questão, como manipular o array via múltiplos *controllers?

Comment: Você pode utilizar um service para armazenar o valor a ser compartilhado entre os diferentes controllers. A resposta aceita desta pergunta cobre o mesmo escopo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64612/angular-usar-mesmo-scope-entre-controles/64615#64615

Answer (score 1):

Aí você precisa declarar o array em um scope global, não dentro dos controllers.

Cada controller possui o seu scope específico, mas quando você cria uma variável em escopo global (no módulo que engloba todos os controllers de seu interesse) você consegue acessar essa variável em todos os controllers.

Não necessariamente usar um factory. Quando você inicia o seu código angular você declara um módulo, que é o principal da sua aplicação, certo?

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
```

em seguida você atribui a esse modulo os seus services, controllers, etc... utilizando:

```
app.controller(...
app.service(...
...
```

se você declarar suas variáveis fora do scopo desses controllers, services, elas estarão dentro do módulo "myApp", que é o "pai" desses outros. Assim, você tem as variáveis em um scope global, pois todos os filhos irão acessar essa variável que está no pai.

Comment: Seria o caso de usar um factory?

Comment: não necessariamente... mas pode ser usado um Module... o seu modulo principal mesmo, que você declara no começo do código angular.

Answer (score 0):

Como cada controller possui um escopo que no seu caso seria o '$scope', mas esse escopo irá 'morrer' quando alternar de controllers. Então sugiro utilizar o $rootScope do angularJS (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope). Com ele voce pode criar um array detro do $rootScope e que seja acessível para todos controllers.

Ex: $rootScope.array.customerData = [];

app.controller('RequestedDestinationModalController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {

var object = {};
$rootScope.array.customerData.push(object);

...